Как из БД вывести ячейку?
Всем привет, как с помощью sqlalchemy и aiogram сделать команду /kick @username причина
по части aiogram все готово, осталось передать в команду данные.
Мне нужно из таблицы бд, где есть telegram id и telegram username, вывести telegram id, зная username пользователя… как это сделать?

Ну простейший select же по идее.

Это можно сделать простым SQL-запросом:
SELECT <id> FROM <table_name> WHERE <user_name> = "{username}"

Вместо <id> ты пишешь название своего столбца, в котором хранятся id пользователей, вместо <table_name> - название таблицы, и вместо <user_name> - столбец, в котором хранится user_name.
Советую тебе прилагать больше информации, когда задаешь вопросы на форумах.

мне нужен запрос sqlalchemy, а не дефолтный

и вообще не это предлагаете вытащить, информации достаточно, к сожалению Вы не поняли вопроса

Можно использовать обычный scalar-запрос:
userid = await sess.scalar(select(User.id).where(User.username == username))

Отформатируй, если надо это под свою модель базы данных.
